# Проблемы раскодирования base64 (появляются пустые строки) Lua (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: lua, base64

Я хочу использовать Lua для хранения pdf в теле документа LuaLaTeX и его извлечения при компиляции документа.

Для кодирования документа использую `https://base64.guru/` или
утилитой Windows `certutil -encodehex -f test.txt enc.txt 0x40000001`

Таким образом файл выгружается из документа LuaLaTeX:

```lua
\directlua{%
io.output("base64.tex");
io.write((mime.unb64("U3RyaW5nLTENClN0cmluZy0y")));}
```

Исходный файл состоит из 2-х строчек:

```
String-1
String-2
```

После раскодирования получаю 3 строки (появляется пустая строка)

```
String-1

String-2
```

Аналогично и с файлом pdf. Его размер увеличивается после кодирования/декодирования.

Я нашел документацию: [https://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/mime.html#unb64](https://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/mime.html#unb64) но не могу разобраться. Мне кажется проблема в что при это из-за  \r\n последовательности при декодировании, это окончание строки в стиле Windows.

Текст работает только этим кодером https://appdevtools.com/base64-encoder-decoder

`U3RyaW5nLTEKU3RyaW5nLTI=` - это рабочий вариант

`U3RyaW5nLTENClN0cmluZy0y` - это не рабочий (такой у всех кодеров на выходе!)

`certutil -encodehex -f test.txt enc.txt 0x80000001` (Use \n line terminators instead of \r\n) - Это вариант тоже не работает

Помогите сделать, чтобы работало.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: *"Исходный файл состоит из 2-х строчек"* - исходные (и выходные) данные должны быть в бинарном виде, а если будете работать с ними, как с текстом, то помимо проблем с переносом строк, еще получите проблемы с кодировкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так все работает:

```
\directlua{%
 local file = io.open("base64.txt", "wb");
 file:write((mime.unb64("U3RyaW5nLTENClN0cmluZy0y")));
 file:close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Кодер base64 ни при чём - что ты подал на вход, то и будет на выходе
Будет ли выбрано CR или CRLF - зависит от текстового редактора (или от того компонента, который генерирует или показывает текст)
После раскодирования просто сам руками замени CRLF на LF

```
io.write((mime.unb64("U3RyaW5nLTENClN0cmluZy0y"):gsub("\r\n", "\n")));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. @ESkri